# Auto Smooth Image zooming in Windows phone8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Hi I am new to windows phone 8.How to make an image to zoom in and zoom out  smoothly   in an automatic manner windows phone 8.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You mean `Pinch-Zoom`?

Comment: Do you want just an animation of zooming-in and zooming-out an image without user interaction?

Comment: Yes.I need animation of image zooming without user interaction......

Answer (score 0):

So to start with, you could use the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034) in order to use the `Gesture` provided by `CodePlex`. A workaround has been already done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678268/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-images-in-wp7). 
Or else another option would be to go with the `ManipulationStarted` events for an image.

Reference: [Smooth pinch-zooming and panning on Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652618/)

Another option could be, to use the `Viewport` control for `Windows Phone`which could handle `flick` and `pinch` gestures. Better if you could have a glance at the sample given by [msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Smooth-flick-and-zoom-with-7760c7f7). There could be more options out there, it would be better if you could give a search on them.